# How to send value which contains backward slash, dynamically in postman request body?

Tags: api, dynamic, attributes, automated-tests, postman

I am using Postman for testing POST API.
Purpose of API : The API should download some data at given "path".

**Case : 1**
When I give hard-coded path in request body-

```
{
    "downloadPath": "D:\\folderName",
    "objectID": "1234"
}
```

I get expected response in this case.

**Case : 2**
I want to send this path and ID dynamically.
Now the Request Body looks like-

```
{
    "downloadPath": "{{path}}",
    "objectID": "{{id}}"
}
```

It reads the values from JSON file which looks like-

```
[
{
    "path":"D:\\folderName1",
    "id":"1234"
},
{
    "path":"D:\\folderName2",
    "id":"5678"
}
]
```

It does not give expected response.

**Note:** When I tried hard-coded path with dynamic id, it works fine

What could be the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you save the request tab after trying this out in the Collection Runner?

Comment: 1. @DannyDainton I really don't get what do you mean by saving request tab after collection runner.

2. Also I would like to add to above explanation:
 after running collection I get correct body values in console as per JSON file.

 downloadPath: "D:\folderName1"
 objectID: "1234"

  but unable to get expected response.
 Is it something related to backward slash present in the path?

 Because, when I give hard-coded path and then give only object ID dynamically through JSON file, it works.

Comment: Making changes to the request builder tab, the place where you craft the request. If you make changes here and don't save them, the Collection Runner won't automatically know about them. I just wanted to rule that out. Log out the `pm.iterationData.get('path')` to the console to see what value it being used during runtime.

Comment: Yes, I tried the console log and it shows correct values.